# How to convert an Excel range to a List<String>?

Tags: c#, excel

I'd like to get a list of strings from an Excel range where the data could be mixed types (strings, doubles, etc.).  I tried using this:

```
List<string> rangeToList(Excel.Range inputRng)
    {
        object[,] cellValues = (object[,])inputRng.Value2;
        List<string> lst = cellValues.Cast<string>().ToList();
        return lst;
    }
```

But the line with `Cast<string>` returns this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'
```

How can I convert this array of objects into my desired list?

Comment: @PortlandRunner, no, that causes a compiler error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`.

Comment: Yet you accepted a `.ToString()` answer :-)

Comment: @PortlandRunner, I interpreted your suggestion to mean `List<string> lst = cellValues.ToString().ToList();` which gave the compiler error.  Maybe I misinterpreted your advice; it would have been better if I'd posted the new line of code in addition to the compiler error.

Comment: No worries, I wasn't very clear in my comment but I'm glad you have an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Cast` won't implicitly convert a number to a string, but you can call `ToString` on each object:

```
List<string> lst = cellValues.Cast<object>()
                             .Select(o => o.ToString())
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Tried to use this (+1) and it works, but needs an extra "()" (i.e. cellValues.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList(); )

Answer (score 13):

First you should cast to `object` to make list of object and after that you should use `ConvertAll` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to convert `object` to `string`.

```
List<string> rangeToList(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range inputRng)
{
    object[,] cellValues = (object[,])inputRng.Value2;
    List<string> lst = cellValues.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x=> Convert.ToString(x));
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: great answer! I think that's what the accepted answer should be. It's clean and concise. Thank you,