# Another Look at Transferring Excel data rows to an Array (Edited)

Tags: c#, excel, arraylist

For clarification, I am trying to transfer each, whole Excel row into list. In the case of the simplified example, I am trying to transfer the first row into a string array.

I have worked through several posts on the topic of converting each row of an Excel spreadsheet and transferring each row to a List, including this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235066/how-to-convert-an-excel-range-to-a-liststring)

Despite playing around with examples, I still get a conversion error. I narrowed down my program to a simple example, just offloading the first row, which contains column headers into a string array, and I am getting an error saying cannot convert a generic list  to a string[].

I can print the first line using `Console.Write(String.Format(dataRange.Value2.ToString() + " ")`, but cannot save the first line.

Here is the simplified program that produces the error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string [] m_column_headings;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbv = excel.Workbooks.Open("H:\\my_documents\\testFile.xlsx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wx = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

Range dataRange = (Range)wx.Cells[1, 1];
m_column_headings = dataRange.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList(); <--- This line gets the error.
```

Based on the answer, I made the following modifications to keep the types correct, but I am not able to see what I assigned.

```
dataRange = (Range)wx.Cells[1, 1];
m_column_headings = 
  dataRange.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: have you ever tried to use the epplus package? I found it to be A+ for working with excel objects

Comment: Forget interop! Use epplus. If you need POCOs extracred, try this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/zorgoz.EPPlus.TableAsEnumerable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve `string Array` but then asking the code to return `.ToList()`. Either convert m_column_headings to a list, or change the return type to `.ToArray()`

i.e.
`m_column_headings = dataRange.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();`

Comment: Where is the `.Select(o => o.ToString()) documented? It looks like a in-line function.

Comment: Have no idea what you are tying yo do. Especially cell(1,1) will only return one cell. Why you trying to get list out of it, have no idea. Have just responded to arrays vs list error

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answer and comments. They helped jog me into figuring out what was going wrong:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbv = excel.Workbooks.Open("H:\\my_documents\\town\\personnel\\May 18 MuniRosterDetailReport.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wx = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
            Range dataRange = null;
            int totalColumns = wx.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
            int totalRows = wx.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                List<string> m_column_headings = new List<string>();
                dataRange = (Range)wx.UsedRange;

                int row = 1;
                for(int colIdx = 1; colIdx < (totalColumns + 1); colIdx++)
                {
                    Range tempRange = (Range )wx.Cells[row, colIdx];
                    m_column_headings.Add(String.Format(tempRange.Value2.ToString() + ","));
                }


                int i = 0;
            wbv.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excel.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```